# Deploying Rails Applications with Unicorn to Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I'm trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails app to Heroku with Unicorn. I followed the [tutorial on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) website. But it shows:

> Precompiling assets failed.

Here is the running result:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
   [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
   rake aborted!
   uninitialized constant Rack::Timeout
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/config/initializers/timeout.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:649:in `block in load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.rc1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `each'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:286:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:262:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:346:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

   Precompiling assets failed.


   Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I use Ruby2.0, Ruby on Rails 4.1.0.rc1.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the timeout setting:

```
rm config/initializers/timeout.rb
```

Heroku times-out all requests at 30 seconds but the process will continue running in the background.

If you want to avoid that, re-add the line above but [put rack-timeout in your Gemfile](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is actually related to `Rack::Timeout` and not asset compilation.

```
uninitialized constant Rack::Timeout
/tmp/build_d3989303-c1d8-4020-9b98-eb9e1834f0d0/config/initializers/timeout.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Have you included the rack-timeout gem in your gemfile? And ran `bundle install` after that?

```
gem "rack-timeout"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the following:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

If this fails, you could always precompile your production assets, add them to your codebase and push them to heroku yourself.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -m 'serving up my precompiled assets'
git push origin master
git push origin heroku
```